# Chrome old version 107 reduce innerHeight when open keyboard

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I am using React to develop my website, in my website I have a logic to check when the user is in landscape mode by `window.innerWidth` < `window.innerHeight`.

But when the user opens the keyboard from the input tag, it reduces the screen's height to be smaller than the `window.innerWidth`, I have tested some new versions, but don't meet that issue. How can I fix it in the old version?